# @each with an @include mixin

Tags: css, fonts, sass, google-webfonts

I have a dropdown of 30 fonts where I'd like the font of the dropdown to also display the Google Font (for visual representation, of course!) example text.

I have the HTML with the ID's, for example: `font-oswald-light`, `font-oswald-reg`, `font-oswald-bold`.

Using the @each directive, I wanted to do something like this:

```
@each $font-name, $font-mixin in (lato, Lato-Light),
                                  (open_sans, Open_Sans-Light),
                                  (oswald, Oswald-Light),
                                  (raleway, Raleway-Light),
                                  (roboto, Roboto-Light),
                                  (source_sans_pro, Source_Sans_Pro-Light),
                                  (ubuntu, Ubuntu-Light) {
  #font-#{$font-name}-light {
    @include #{$font-mixin};
  }
}
```

create the font-family:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=......)

@mixin Lato-Light {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@mixin Lato-Reg {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

@mixin Lato-Bold {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

However, the @each does not like the `@include` inside to display the font-family.  I'm not using any libraries (bourbon, compass, etc) to create the font-face().

My question is: what would be a way to dynamically create the @each font-ID list so it doesn't error out when trying to @include the families?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#font-#{$font-name}-light {
  @include #{$font-mixin};
}
```

First of all, this code can't work. Interpolation does not work this way in Sass. Sass expects an ***identifier*** after the `@include` keyword and when it comes across this code, it evaluates `$font-mixin` to the value represented by the variable and that's all it is, a *value*. Sass will not interpret that ***value*** as an ***identifier***

Secondly you don't need to create a mixin for every single font. That approach is not flexible and even less maintainable.

I suggest one using one `mixin` that will loop through a `fonts map` to dynamically generate the css you want.

```
$fonts-list:(
  lato-light: ("Lato", sans-serif) 300 normal,
  lato-reg: ("Lato", sans-serif) 400 normal,
  lato-bold: ("Lato", sans-serif) 700 normal,
  oswald-light: ("Oswald", sans-serif) 200 normal,
  oswald-reg: ("Oswald", sans-serif) 400 normal
);


@mixin fonts($family, $weight, $style) {
  font-family: $family;
  font-weight: $weight;
  font-style: $style;
}

@each $font, $attributes in $fonts-list {
  #font-#{$font} {
    @include fonts(nth($attributes, 1), nth($attributes, 2), nth($attributes, 3));
  }
}
```

The compiled CSS looks like this

```
#font-lato-light {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

#font-lato-reg {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

#font-lato-bold {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

#font-oswald-light {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
}

#font-oswald-reg {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

You can decide to have multiple ***font maps*** to store fonts based on variations i.e `$fonts-light`, which stores all the ***light variations*** of the fonts, `$fonts-reg`, which stores all the ***regular variations*** of the fonts... And then you could loop through each of them the same way. It all depends on the structure you prefer. I hope this helps

Comment: just want to say 1) Super Thanks for the quick response :), and 2) this worked like a charm.  I was going down the right path, but clearly wasn't quite wearing the right shoes!  haha.

Comment: Yeah your shoes were taking you down the path of a gazillion mixins :D 
You're more than welcome, happy to help